# Проблема маршрутизации. После срабатывания timeout не работает переход на /login

Tags: java, reactjs, java-ee, spring-boot, spring-security

Есть приложение написано на стеке Spring + React, все работает нормально кроме перехода на страницу авторизации /login после срабатывания timeout.

```java
 @Controller
 public class ListController {

     @RequestMapping(path="/login")
      public String login() {
        return "login";
      }

     @RequestMapping("/login-error")
      public String loginError(Model model) {
         System.out.println("method login error");
        model.addAttribute("loginError", true);
        return "login";
      }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/*")
    public String start() {
        System.out.println("RUN Method start()");
        return "index";
    }
    }
```

```java
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        registry.addViewController("/general/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

    }

}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());

     http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/login").maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false).expiredUrl("/login");

         http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/login/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("READ","WRITE")
            .and()

         .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
            .failureUrl("/login-error")
            .permitAll()
            .and()

         .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
         }

       @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                    "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers","Origin","Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "Authorization"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }

}
```

application.properties

```java
server.port = 8080
server.servlet.contextPath=/general
server.session.timeout=1

spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

[image: На изображении видно что переход есть но браузер не обновил страницу]

последний вызов getUser возвращает код 302 идет перенаправление на /login, если обновить страницу то возвращается на /login

```
на стороне react сделал вот так 
 fetch('/general/api/getUser')  
      .then(  
        function(response) {  
          if (response.status !== 200) {  
            location.reload()
            return;  
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил на стороне клиента строку обработки перенаправления if(response.redirected) location = response.url

```
 fetch('/general/api/getUser')  
      .then(  
        function(response) {  
          if (response.status !== 200) {  
            location.reload()
            return;  
          }
if(response.redirected) location = response.url
//логика обработки ответа
})
```